# AWS Cloudformation: Take an AMI as a parameter, otherwise fallback to using a Map

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'd like to setup a Cloudformation template in the following way:

1) Check for a parameter from the user.  If provided, use that.

2) If no parameter is provided, fall back to using a map like the following:

```
  AWSRegionArch2AMI:
    eu-central-1:
      HVM64: ami-d11dc4ff
    us-east-1:
      HVM64: ami-a13749a2
    us-west-1:
      HVM64: ami-fdd8428a
```

The important part here is the per region defaults; I need to use the template across regions, so I need to have region-specific defaults.

Does anyone know a good way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [Conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-sample-templates.html).  Basically, you define a variable that's either true or false based on a check that you define, and then you can have the template fork based on that value.

Below is an example template that creates a single EC2 instance using that method of AMI selection:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Example mostly pulled from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-sample-templates.html",
    "Mappings": {
        "AWSRegionArch2AMI": {
            "eu-central-1": {"HVM64": "ami-d11dc4ff"},
            "us-east-1": {"HVM64": "ami-a13749a2"},
            "us-west-1": {"HVM64": "ami-fdd8428a"}
        }
    },
    "Parameters": {
        "AMI": {
            "Description": "AMI to use.",
            "AllowedPattern": "(ami-[0-9a-f]{8}){0,1}",
            "Default": "",
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Conditions": {
        "UseDefaultAMI": {
            "Fn::Equals": [
                {"Ref": "AMI"},
                ""
            ]
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "EC2Instance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "ImageId": {
                    "Fn::If": [
                        "UseDefaultAMI",
                        {"Fn::FindInMap": [
                                "AWSRegionArch2AMI",
                                {"Ref": "AWS::Region"},
                                "HVM64"
                        ]},
                        {"Ref": "AMI"}
                    ]
                },
                "InstanceType": "m3.medium"
            }
        }
    }
}
```